Readtrace.exe to convert to .rml file from SQLReplay Trace file
I am using RML utility for performance testing. Needs help on issue I am facing, while converting the SQL replay Trace collected from production and converting it into .rml file using Readtrace.exe getting following error -
12/04/24 21:54:51.623 [0X0000224C] -ID:\Traces\TestTrace.trc
12/04/24 21:54:51.661 [0X0000224C] -oE:\demo
12/04/24 21:54:51.670 [0X0000224C] -SEC2AMAZ-NGKE64A
12/04/24 21:54:51.670 [0X0000224C] -T28
12/04/24 21:54:51.671 [0X0000224C] -T29
12/04/24 21:54:51.672 [0X0000224C] Using language id (LCID): 1024 [English_United States.1252] for character formatting with NLS: 0x00060403 and Defined: 0x00060403
12/04/24 21:54:51.672 [0X0000224C] Attempting to cleanup existing RML files from previous execution
12/04/24 21:54:51.673 [0X0000224C] Using extended RowsetFastload synchronization
12/04/24 21:54:51.674 [0X0000224C] Establishing initial database connection
12/04/24 21:54:51.675 [0X0000224C] Server: EC2AMAZ-NGKE64A
12/04/24 21:54:51.675 [0X0000224C] Database: PerfAnalysis
12/04/24 21:54:51.675 [0X0000224C] Authentication: Windows
12/04/24 21:54:51.875 [0X0000224C] Using SQLOLEDB version 11.0.7462.6
12/04/24 21:54:51.880 [0X0000224C] Connected to SQL Server Version, Major: 15, Minor: 0, Build: 2000
12/04/24 21:54:51.907 [0X0000224C] Creating or clearing the performance database
12/04/24 21:54:51.960 [0X0000224C] Query store enabled for performance analysis database
12/04/24 21:54:52.947 [0X0000224C] Traced server version: 15.00:2000
12/04/24 21:54:52.949 [0X0000224C] Processing file: D:\Traces\TestTrace.trc (SQL vNext / SQL Azure*)
12/04/24 21:54:52.956 [0X0000224C] Validating core events exist
12/04/24 21:54:52.980 [0X0000224C] Validating necessary events exist for analysis
12/04/24 21:54:52.986 [0X0000224C] WARNING: The following trace events were not captured: [Showplan Statistics]. Review the help file to ensure that you have collected the appropriate set of events and columns for your intended analysis.
12/04/24 21:54:53.017 [0X0000224C] Validating necessary events exist for RML breakout
12/04/24 21:54:53.023 [0X0000224C] WARNING: Event [Server: Server Memory Change] missing from trace
12/04/24 21:54:53.066 [0X0000224C] WARNING REPLAY: The following trace events were not captured: [TSQL: Unprepare SQL, Transactions:SQLTransaction, Transactions:DTCTransaction, Transactions:TM:Begin Tran starting, Transactions:TM:Begin Tran completed, Transactions:TM:Commit Tran starting, Transactions:TM:Commit Tran completed, Transactions:TM:Rollback Tran starting, Transactions:TM:Rollback Tran completed, Transactions:TM:Save Tran starting, Transactions:TM:Save Tran completed, Transactions:TM:Promote Tran starting, Transactions:TM:Promote Tran completed]. Review the help file to ensure that you have collected the appropriate set of events and columns for RML replay needs.  Lack of these events can lead to severe replay problems.
12/04/24 21:54:53.071 [0X0000224C] WARNING: Honoring user request to override RML event requirements. This could result in unexpected RML output and should not be used in replay attempts
12/04/24 21:54:53.144 [0X0000224C] Reached the end of the trace; found [TRACE_STOP_EVENT].
12/04/24 21:54:53.195 [0X0000224C] Reads completed
12/04/24 21:54:53.206 [0X00003314] WARNING: One or more sessions are missing prevent. This may be from a torn start of the trace for the SPID or PRE events were not captured.  Using sequence number of -1 so replay attempts to process the event immediately.
12/04/24 21:54:53.218 [0X0000224C] Signaling worker threads to complete final actions.
12/04/24 21:54:53.237 [0X0000224C] Waiting for the worker threads to complete final actions.
12/04/24 21:54:53.268 [0X0000224C] Performing general cleanup actions.
12/04/24 21:54:53.268 [0X0000224C] Reducing cached memory in background
12/04/24 21:54:53.299 [0X0000224C] Total Events Processed: 186
12/04/24 21:54:53.305 [0X0000224C]  Total Events Filtered: 4
12/04/24 21:54:53.422 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblUniqueBatches: loaded ~14 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.433 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblUniqueStatements: loaded ~1 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.454 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblUniquePlans: loaded ~0 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.471 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblUniquePlanRows: loaded ~0 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.489 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblBatches: loaded ~31 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.540 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblStatements: loaded ~11 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.567 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblPlans: loaded ~0 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.570 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblPlanRows: loaded ~0 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.631 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblInterestingEvents: loaded ~0 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.647 [0X0000224C] Table ReadTrace.tblConnections: loaded ~13 rows
12/04/24 21:54:53.711 [0X0000224C] WARNING: One or more warning conditions exist that may affect the quality of the analysis data.  See PerfAnalysis.ReadTrace.tblWarnings table and the ReadTrace log for complete details.
12/04/24 21:54:53.769 [0X0000224C] INFO: Cleaning up unique batch hash table
12/04/24 21:54:53.830 [0X0000224C] INFO: Cleaning up unique statement hash table
12/04/24 21:54:53.844 [0X0000224C] INFO: Cleaning up unique plan hash table
12/04/24 21:54:53.897 [0X0000224C] INFO: Cleaning up unique procedure hash table
12/04/24 21:54:53.909 [0X0000224C] Indexing tables...
12/04/24 21:54:54.437 [0X0000224C] Doing post-load data cleanup...
12/04/24 21:54:55.174 [0X0000224C] Computing partial aggregates...
12/04/24 21:54:55.562 [0X0000224C] Building analysis indexes ...
12/04/24 21:54:55.729 [0X0000224C] Data load completed.
12/04/24 21:54:55.730 [0X0000224C] Using execution path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Corporation\RMLUtils\
12/04/24 21:54:55.741 [0X0000224C] Launching [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Corporation\RMLUtils\Reporter.exe]
12/04/24 21:54:55.826 [0X0000224C] Launch failure exit code: 259
12/04/24 21:54:55.831 [0X0000224C] Attempt to launch Reporter failed.  Check the error log and your RML installation.
12/04/24 21:54:55.832 [0X0000224C] *******************************************************************************
* ReadTrace encountered one or more ERRORS. An error condition typically      *
* stops processing early and the ReadTrace output may be unusable.            *
* Review the log file for details.                                            *
*******************************************************************************
12/04/24 21:54:55.832 [0X0000224C] ***** ReadTrace exit code: -23

Context: Utilizing RML utilities for performance testing the new SQL Server instance as a part of migration to AWS RDS.
Collected the peak workloads from production SQL Server in a trace file (using TSQL Replay template).
While attempting to convert the (.TRC) file to RML file utilizing the ReadTrace.exe utility as required, the conversion process fail generating the errors above.
ReadTrace.exe (Version: 9.04.0102) ProdSQLServer-2016

Hey Krishna, you have a wonderful name, however, if you want help please elaborate more on your question, format it nicely, add more information and context, make it easy for people to spend time and look at your issue. consider this. cheers

Thanks, Marcello, for the quick response and compliment to my name.
Context: Utilizing RML utilities for performance testing the new SQL Server instance as a part of migration to AWS RDS. Collected the peak workloads from production SQL Server in a trace file (using TSQL Replay template). While attempting to convert the (.TRC) file to RML file utilizing the ReadTrace.exe utility as required, the conversion process fail generating the errors above.  Sincerely appreciate your help in advance to assist me with the issue resolution please.
ReadTrace.exe (Version: 9.04.0102) ProdSQLServer-2016
